# typeid for polymorphic pointers?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, typeid

I don't understand why pointers aren't polymorphic types, since we can use base class pointers, which are pointing to derived classes, to call derived class' virtual function. This suggests at runtime, the system can determine if a pointer is polymorphic, doesn't it?

(This is a follow-up question from [typeid for polymorphic types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202877/typeid-for-polymorphic-types))

Comment: Base class pointers do not point to derived classes. They are pointing to base classes. This pretty much voids the rest of your conclusions.

Comment: @VladLazarenko Pointers do not point to classes at all. They point to objects, and those can be of base class, or derived class type. I think that's what the OP means (although, indeed, the wording isn't optimal).

Comment: What would be different if pointers were considered polymorphic types? Would you be able to do something you cannot do now?

Comment: @jogojapan: OK, instance of the class, or object, it doesn't matter. Pointer to base never points to derived. Never.

Comment: @VladLazarenko What I mean is a situation like this: `struct A {}; struct B : A {}; int main() { A* ap = new B; }` Here, `ap` is declared as pointer to base class, but it actually points to an object of the derived class.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I was originally using typeid on pointers to check types and throw out error if types aren't what they're supposed to be. I suppose I'd have to use typedid on references now as they're truly polymorphic.

Comment: @jogojapan: No, `ap` in this case points to A's part of B. Which may or may not be the same (depends on class sizes). This is fundamental, compilers adjust such addresses automatically either in compile-time or run-time (think about why pointer to member function is twice as larger as a regular pointer).

Comment: @VladLazarenko I suppose the point is that `ap` will (if there are virtual functions in `A`) have polymorphic characteristics, e.g. when it comes to virtual method calls, but also casts to derived types, and, most importantly, when you apply `typeid` to `*ap`, i.e. `typeid(*ap)` will return `B` as the type. This is why people usually refer to this situation as "`ap` points to a derived-class object", regardless of what happens on the low level.

Comment: @Vlad Lazarenko: I understand what you mean, but you are trying to insist on your version of informal terminology. Semi-informally, base pointer *can* *point* to derived object. The C++ language has concepts of *static* and *dynamic* type of an expression. When base pointer `*p` is initialized with address of polymorphic derived object, it means that the dynamic type of `*p` expression is derived class type. In this case it is perfectly valid to say that `p` points to derived object in a sense that "dynamic type of `*p` is derived". It is an accepted semi-informal terminology.

Comment: @VladLazarenko: The standard itself says in several places that a base pointer points to a derived object, so this is a valid and established terminology. You can always say that p points to a subobject of type A if you want. The complete object is of type B and p points to it too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your question suffers from incorrect usage of terminology. C++ language makes a very clear distinction between pointers themselves and objects these pointers point to. Pointer types are not polymorphic. There's nothing polymorphic about the pointer itself. What can really be polymorphic is *the type the pointer points to*. When a pointer points to a polymorphic type, we often [informally] call it *polymorphic pointer* (just as a shorthand for "a pointer that points to a polymorphic type"). But when it comes to things like `typeid`, they see things very formally. For `typeid` pointer types are never polymorphic.

And the compiler does not determine whether the pointer is polymorphic or not at run-time. This simple distinction is always immediately known at compile-time. Again, a pointer is referred to as *polymorphic* if it is declared as a pointer to *polymorphic type*. *Polymorphic type* is a class type that contains virtual functions (directly or indirectly). Obviously, the property of being polymorphic is a purely compile-time property of a type.

The only thing that is determined at run-time in such cases case is *which* specific type the pointed object has at the given moment.

Comment: +1 for careful use of terminology. It made me aware of my own sloppy use of the words.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. This all makes a lot of sense now. :)

Answer (score 13):

In fact, the Standard (C++11) uses the term *polymorphic class type*, rather than *polymorphic type* when it describes the behaviour of `typeid`:

Firstly, here it describes what happens when `typeid` is applied to an lvalue of class type (i.e. the case when it does what you expect):

> (§5.2.8/2) When `typeid` is applied to a glvalue expression whose type is a polymorphic class type (10.3), the result refers to a `std::type_info` object representing the type of the most derived object (1.8) (that is, the dynamic type) to which the glvalue refers. [...]

But when you apply it to a pointer (i.e. not to an lvalue of class type), the rule below applies:

> (§5.2.8/3) When `typeid` is applied to an expression other than a glvalue of a polymorphic class type, the result refers to a `std::type_info` object representing the static type of the expression. [...]

It says you get the static (not the dynamic) type, i.e. you get the declared type of the pointer, not the type of object it is actually pointing to.

So, yes, pointers have polymorphic characteristics as you describe, but not when it comes to the result of `typeid`.

(In fact, all of their polymorphic characteristics (including, in particular, polymorphic member function calls) only manifest themselves when some sort of explicit dereferencing, either using `*` or using `->`, is involved. So you should really say that the pointers themselves aren't polymorphic; only the objects you get when you dereference them are.)